# Suppress needless dialogs from kdiff3?

Tags: mercurial, kdiff3

I use kdiff3 on Windows as the visual merge tool for TortoiseHG / Mercurial.

Often when doing a merge or rebase it will show a dialog like this:

[image]

Another variation is that the two files being merged were "binary equal".

Since these messages are basically saying that there is no conflicts / nothing to do, I'd like to suppress them - is that possible?

---

I don't see anything pertinent in the kdiff3 [command line options](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although having a bit misleading name, `--auto` option does what you want.

[From the documentation:](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html)

> `--auto`                    No GUI if all conflicts are auto-solvable. (Needs `-o file`)

This help text can also be accessing from the command line with `kdiff3 --help`.